# Configuration required for NUGET Package Manager to cerate a package that does not set PrivateAssets to all

Tags: nuget

So I have been up and down the net and looked at several different docs for config and cannot find the answer to this.

I am trying to create a nuget package that has only got some dlls in it.  This is created from a nuspec file or using the Nuget Package Manager application. According to the documentation, this is really simple.  You drag and drop the files that you want to include for the application or in the nuspec file, you add a group called files and then add file elements.  This is documented really nicely in SO as well as several other sites.

The problem that I am having is that when I get the package from the store, it is installed or included into the project like so:

```
<PackageReference Include="MyPackage" Version="1.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

So now none of my references resolve until I remove the PrivateAssets and IncludeAssets from the project file.  Then Unload the project file and reload and then the Compile Time Assemblies are listed for my package and the project compiles because it can find the libraries in the global packages directory.

My question is what/how do I configure either via the nuspec file or the nuget application so that when I install the package I don't have this problem?

I have also looked at other packages that are the same, meaning that they are just packages that include a dll and not a dll that is built from a project.  I have compared those packages nuspec files and there is no difference. By process of elimination I think I have ruled out VS2019, the nuget config files, the private nuget server.  It has to be something I am doing wrong.

Hopefully someone can help me.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Right so I figured it out.

It seems that the current Nuget Package Explorer (6.0.64), which is what was one of the solutions discussed to accomplish what I was trying to do, as well as the current versions of nuget pack CLI and dotnet pack CLI, do not add the

```
<developmentDependency>false</developmentDependency>
```

to the nuspec file that is included in the package once it is built.

No matter what configuration you set in the Nuget Package Explorer or the config of the nuspec file used to create the package, the developmentDependency tag is not added.

So my solution was once the package was built, open the package using winzip or 7zip and edit the nuspec file.  Add the missing tag and then save and push to the repo.

Now when you install it, visual studio does not set the PrivateAssets and IncludeAssets and everything works like it should.

Hope this helps someone.